# XDocument.Root.Element returns null

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have XML which is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RootNodeName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" MyAttribute="7" xmlns="mylink">
  <IsValid>false</IsValid>
  <Name>some matrix</Name>
  ...Some more nodes...
</RootNodeName>
```

and code which is like:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(myXmlString);
Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Element("Name"));
```

and console shows just an empty space since `doc.Root.Element("Name")` returns `null` =(

While I can find this Element among `doc.Root.Elements()` results.
`doc.Root.Attribute("MyAttribute")` gives correct result as well.

What is wrong with it/me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `<Name>` element is in the `mylink` namespace:

```
XNamespace mylink = "mylink";

Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Element(mylink + "Name"));
```

Comment: That was just great! Thanks =) I should read documentation more carefully =)

Comment: What if it says: `xmlns=""`? Thanks