# XDocument Root.Elements() returning null

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to parse an xml file generated by running unit tests, but the `xml.Root.Elements()` is coming up as null.

Here a sample of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestRun id="2ece436d-907d-4f59-9c81-0544b2f4f7cd" name="redacted" runUser="redacted" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <TestSettings name="Default Test Settings" id="e00bb4af-1518-4b40-9905-19fa7b190f68">
    ... 
  </TestSettings>
  <Times creation="2015-02-18T11:47:02.7188640-05:00" queuing="2015-02-18T11:47:03.1819103-05:00" start="2015-02-18T11:47:03.2819203-05:00" finish="2015-02-18T11:47:05.5571478-05:00" />
  <ResultSummary outcome="Failed">
    <Counters total="74" executed="74" passed="73" error="0" failed="1" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
  </ResultSummary>
```

I want to retreive the `<ResultSummary>`'s `outcome`, but all `Element()` and `Elements()` calls on `xml.Root` are returning null.

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(resultFile);
var outcome = xml.Root
    .Element("TestRun")
    .Element("ResultSummary")
    .Attribute("outcome")
    .Value;
```

I tried adding the namespace like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13402673/526704) but I'm still getting the same results:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(resultFile);
XNamespace ns = "http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010";
var outcome = xml.Root
    .Element(ns + "TestRun")
    .Element("ResultSummary")
    .Attribute("outcome")
    .Value;
```

Also, I'm not sure if `Root` is supposed to return `<TestRun>` or not, I tried running `xml.Root.Element("ResultSummary")` and I still get null.

How can I read this xml file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `XDocument.Root` gets the root element of the XML Tree. And in your case it is `TestRun`.
And, for getting object from a local name and a namespace, you can use `XName.Get(string, string)` method:

So, change your code as:

```
string ns = "http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010";
var outcome = xml.Root
            .Element(XName.Get("ResultSummary", ns))
            .Attribute("outcome")
            .Value;
```

The result is: ***Failed***

Answer (score 2):

Other way to get the `Namespace` is like this `XNamespace ns = xml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();`

Comment: oh that's nice, so in @farhad's answer you could replace the `ns` variable with `xml.Root.GetDefaultNameSpace().NamespaceName`